# MVC4: Authentication still valid but got redirected to login page after app pool recycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, session

This is weird, after I login then the application pool recycle, the next request always redirects me to login page. The weird thing is that my authentication is still valid. Why does my web redirects me?

Comment: If you keep your data in a session variable, it's normal that during an apppool recycle your authentication gets lost.
You'd best save this in a cookie, on the users end iso in a session on the servers end.

Comment: I use sql to store session, also I use cookie to hold the authentication. I even use machine key to encrypt decrypt the cookies. Like I state in my question, my authentication cookie is not lost. After the app pool being recycle, I still can see that I am logged in. The only problem is that I got redirected to login page. This is quite a trouble if the user is in the middle of important transaction / form submission, it can fail.